# Какие функции использовать для проверки при загрузке картинок на сервер?

Tags: php

Загружаю посредством PHP изображения на сервер.

Нужно проверить тип файла, чтобы загружали только изображения;
нужно проверить размер файла, чтобы не загружались картинки более определённого размера ;
нужно переименовывать каждое изображение, чтобы не было одинаковых имён (интересует генерация уникального имени, чтото типа времени и даты загрузки).

Какие функции для этого использовать?

А также какая функция есть для удаления изображения с сервера по адресу,
вытащенному из базы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если говорить о штатных средствах php:

При загрузке файла в массиве $_FILES возвращается и размер файла и тип загружаемого файла. Так что достаточно задать переменную-массив с предполагаемыми форматами для загрузки и переменную с максимальным размером и проверять на соответствие этим значениям.

Например:

```
$types = array('image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg');
if (!in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $types)){
     echo 'Недопустимый тип файла. Допустимо загружать только изображения: *.gif, *.png, *.jpg';
}
```

Аналогично с размером.

Для генерации уникального имени можно кодировать название файла в md5 с добавлением случайного значения в "хвост".

Например:

```
$file_name = md5($file_name).rand(999,100000);
```

Для получения имени файла (и отделения его расширения) можно сделать:

```
explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name'])
```

Последним значением полученного массива и будет расширение загруженного файла.

Для удаления файла используется unlink.

Comment: А можно использовать time() или microtime() для задания уникального имени файла? Просто не могу понять, что выводят эти функции? Только что попробовал, и тайм() вывел 1372247228. Что это за время такое?

Comment: time() возвращает количество секунд, прошедших с 1 января 1970 до текущего времени

Можно использовать и time, если есть необходимость как-то сохранять и время загрузки файла.
Но только к метке времени надо обязательно еще что-то добавлять. Есть вероятность (хоть и небольшая), что два файла будут загружены одновременно.. 
Поэтому лучше заодно кодировать и название файла, для окончательной уникальности..

Comment: Если что, в похапе имеется встроенная [функция для генерирования уникального имени файла — tempnam](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.tempnam.php), призванная сократить количество случаев подобного неправомерного использования простого генератора псевдослучайных чисел.

Answer (score 2):

> Какая функция есть для удаления
> изображения с сервера по адресу,
> вытащенному из базы?

***unlink()*** должен помочь

Насчет проверки - я бы использовал ***is_file()*** в Вашем случае.

Comment: А разве unset() удаляет файл с сервера? Я думал только переменные.

Comment: Очевидно, имелась ввиду функция unlink()

Comment: Да, unlink() - то, что нужно.

Comment: Исправил..

Answer (score 1):

Как мне советовали в свое время при приеме изображения необходимо пересохранить файл методами php, с возможными изменениями размеров, в необходимом формате. Это позволит избавиться от инъекции кода через файл изображений.

А имя файла можно генерировать например по `md5(id)` . id - из базы, пути к файлу